# Slowness in MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

Tags: asp.net, performance, web-services, iis, asmx

I have a backend IIS server that hosts an ASMX web service. During the past months, this web service has been performing very poorly: requests that usually took around 20ms are now taking around 250ms. After investigating the matter in New Relic, I see that the majority of the time (over 90% of the request processing time - well over 200ms) is being spent on this call:

System.Web.HttpApplication+MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

In all of my other web services, this call takes no more than 1ms.

I have no idea what is this call and why it is performing so poorly. I tried website recycles and IIS resets, but that didn't help. I also tried to google it for hours, but to no avail.

I should also mention that sometimes, for a few brief hours, this problem disappears and the above call is being executed in less than 1ms, as expected.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.